# how to fetch rss from a news website categorically using php?

Tags: php, rss, rss-reader

I need to fetch RSS from a news site on the basis of categories using PHP. I couldn't find any tutorial related to it and neither could I find any website which gives RSS with categories as according to my need the RSS must have a category tag, along with heading, date and detail.

Comment: You should use curl to fetch the RSS feeds. google for "php fetch rss curl" and you will get plenty of examples. here is one I found http://ditio.net/2008/06/19/using-php-curl-to-read-rss-feed-xml/

Comment: Or if you rather user a library, search on github for "php rss". there are plenty of open source libs there which you can use.

Comment: thanks sir. can you please tell me about any news site that gives category attribute in rss.

Comment: sorry but I can't help you there. But I am sure a short web research will reveal which news sites fit your requirements (if any)

Comment: tried for multiple sites, like bbc but they give pubdate, title, detail etc but doesnt gives category tag in rss.xml.